# check for text on page and then redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

If my page says:

> "Code incorect please try again"

then my URL redirect should be:

```
http://site.site.co.uk/index.php#contact
```

I would like to use Jquery, but unsure how to check for this on the page and then redirect?

**I have tried:**

`$("div#contact-form:contains('Code incorect please try again')").attr("location","http://site.site.co.uk/index.php#contact");`

Comment: *If my page says: ...*: what do you mean? Is that Ajax response from server or what? Where is your code you have tried so far?

Comment: This is a PHP echo, but the page is designed in one index.php file.

Comment: added what i have tried.. but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
if ($("#contact-form").is(":contains('Code incorect please try again')")) {
    window.location.href = "http://site.site.co.uk/index.php#contact";
}
```

Comment: will this still find the text if the #contact-form is set to display:none?

Comment: Thanks this works, currently the site is on a test domain, is it possible to do window.location + /index.php#contact ?

Comment: @Super1 Not really. But you can use relative URL: `window.location.href = "/index.php#contact";`

Answer (score 1):

if it's an internal server thing (or you're being precise and any page that says that should get redirected no matter what), js won't help you. for that, you need to look at the web server - if apache, mod_proxy comes to mind, or some of the other modules can evaluate apache's req/res chain and go from there (if it's anything like mod_perl, this is not very fun). iirc, you can do similar things with nginx.

if this is however, a js event, tie into it and alter window.location or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Do this way:-

```
if ($("div#contact-form:contains('Code incorect please try again')").length == 1)
    window.location.replace("http://site.site.co.uk/index.php#contact");
```

Refer **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/f2GaR/5/)**

Comment: @VisioN: You are right. Thanks for pointing. Just I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDiv = $('div#contact-form:containt('Code incorrect please try again'));

if(myDiv.length === 0) {
    location = "http://site.site.co.uk/index.php#contact";
}
```